# Why the Configured Clock Speed was changes after we add two dimm cards

Tags: memory, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel

we have Linux machine with DELL HW , and machine has 256G memory

before adding the new DIMM card with 32G , we verified that `Configured Clock Speed` is 2400MHz

so later we add additional 32G ( 2 DIMM cards , the same DIMM card type that machine already have ) to this machine and after machine boot , we checked the `Configured Clock Speed` by `dmidecode` and we see that it was changed

so `Configured Clock Speed` was changed from `2400MHz` to `1866 MHz`

example

before  adding the new DIMM

```
dmidecode | grep "Configured Clock Speed"
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

after adding the new DIMM

```
  Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

so what could be the reason for that changed? , why by adding one dimm memory , then `Configured Clock Speed` changed like this?

```
Server is Dell PowerEdge R730 and memories are:

Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 3
    Locator: A9
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 2400 MHz
    Manufacturer: 002C0632002C
    Serial Number: 1B42681B
    Asset Tag: 001808A0
    Part Number: 18ASF2G72PDZ-2G3D1
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
    Minimum Voltage:  1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage:  1.2 V
    Configured Voltage:  1.2 V
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly are your computer and RAM models?

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server has 2 sets with 12 DIMM slots each. Each set is organized into 4 memory channels. The first two DIMM slots in each channel supports speeds up to 2400MHz but the third slot supports only 1866MHz. When you start populating the third slot all speeds drop to the lowest speed on the system. Check the owner's manual for more details.

Comment: just to say that we put the  the memory on slots A9 and B9 , so that's it , is it logical ?  , but are these slots belongs to the third slot ??